# blade function so user wont follow itself in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to allow a user to follow a user, but i don't want the user to follow itself.

I'm using [laravel follow](https://github.com/overtrue/laravel-follow), which allows you to follow a user. However, i can follow myself easily and i don't want that. I want it set where you wont be able to follow yourself, this is what i have so far.

**Profile.blade.php**

```
<!-- maybe there should be a blade function that can hide the following below so a user wont be able to follow itself. -->
<div>
    <i ng-click="myfollow({{$user}});" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">Follow</i>
</div>
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function my_follow(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    if(User::find($id)){

        $user->toggleFollow(User::find($id));
    }

}
```

**Main.js**

```
$scope.myfollow = function(user) {
    $http.post('/user/follow/'+ user.id).then(function(result) {
        console.log("user id is:"+ user.id);
    });
};
```

Comment: Do you have the currently authenticated user and its info available within your angular component?

Comment: Do you really need a blade function?  Why not just add an if condition?

Comment: or an if condition, that could work, what will be the best way to use the an if condition in blade so the user wont follow itself.

Comment: @TrollOwl `@if(Auth::id() !== $user)` ?

Comment: thanks but doesnt work, i need to hide to follow button if its user itself. So the user wont be able to see its own follow button. The follow button needs to be visible only if its not the user itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `id` of the current user, by doing `auth()->user()->id`. So just add a check to make sure it's not the same as the ID you're trying to follow:

```
public function my_follow(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    if($user->id != $id && $otherUser = User::find($id)){

        $user->toggleFollow($otherUser);
    }

}
```

Comment: let me try this out.

Comment: how would i be able to hide the follow button though, so the user wont follow himself ?

Comment: nevermind doing the following works `@if($user->id != auth()->user()->id)
                            <div>

                                <i ng-click="myfollow({{$user}});" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">Follow</i>

                            </div>
                        @endif`

Comment: @TrollOwl Glad you were able to figure it out.